# Windows 10: too much data on system disk

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, disk-space

I have windows 10 (updated from windows 8.1). Yesterday I found out that there is no enough space on system disk. I deleted all restore points and unused files using windows utils. It didn't help. Then I turned on setting to show all hidden files and folders to check entire size of all folders on disk C.[image: Size of all folders]

It looks fine but it's not:[image]

Could anyone give me advise how to fix it?

**UPDATE**: Using [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) tool I found out that there is a folder *C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Redis* with size 112Gb! As quick fix I just deleted it using command line. Thanks guys from [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1bec391-b1bd-4d7b-9be8-2643ab4b07b6/windows-10-too-much-data-on-system-disk?forum=win10itprogeneral). I wrote my question there when this post was closed.

Comment: Do you wish to revert your Windows 10 back to Windows 8.1? Your Windows 8.1 is still on the hard drive in the folder `C:\windows.old`. Probably it takes 10 to 20 GB or even more. I am not sure if you can just remove the folder.

Comment: You'll need to find out what is using up all of your space and delete anything that you can.  Don't randomly delete files as you might delete something important.  You can try [this](https://windirstat.info/) tool to see what is using up space on your drive.  Might want to check with someone before deleting anything though, it looks at EVERYTHING not just things wasting space.  If you don't know what it is, it's best to ask before deleting it.  You can break your computer if you delete the wrong thing.  I'm warning you, (and anyone else that reads this), a lot for a very good reason.

Comment: I'd recommend scanning your hard disk with TreeSize (there's a [shareware](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/) and a [free version](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)) to see what's taking up disk space. Both freeware and shareware will show you what's there, the shareware also offers a search for temp files, old files, duplicate files and so on. I agree with Blerg's warning though: Never ever delete stuff before making sure that it's not something important!

Comment: This reminds me of an old Win10 install that did the same to me: Stealing 50-or-so gigs in the "system" area alone.

Comment: You killed your `Redis` database? Are you sure that is wise?

Comment: @Aron Previously I unistalled redis of course. Interesting thing that I just installed it few months ago and haven't used it at all. I'm going to reinstall it with properly settings.